# $db_name, unexpected_t variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this problem with my code
it says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$db_name' (T_VARIABLE) in line 4

```
 <?php

 $db_host = 'localhost'
 $db_name = 'quizzer'
 $db_user = 'root'
 $db_pass = '121212aa'

 $mysqli = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_pass, $db_name);

 if($mysqli->connect_error) {
    printf("Nem sikerult csatlakozni: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error) }

 ?>
```

Comment: A proper IDE with syntax highlighting would save you a lot of trouble. Highlighting shows immediately all syntax errors and where they happen.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this because you don't have semicolons in your code.  PHP requires each line be terminated with a semicolon.

```
<?php

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'quizzer';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '121212aa';

$mysqli = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_pass, $db_name);

if($mysqli->connect_error) {
    printf("Nem sikerult csatlakozni: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error); }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i expected but i thought its not a big problem

Comment: @Nandor'sGames Programming is a very exact art. There are some languages that can try to figure out where to insert semicolons, but it is always better to just add them in to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You missed many ';' when declare parameters,also mysql should take 4 parameters IP,username,password,database name,but you have only 3 of them inserted in constructor.

Comment: actually it takes 0-5 all are optional

Comment: @tim Semantically they would not be correct though. I don't think you can skip the username, and send password.